# Element view not working in controller in CakePHP 4.x

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-4.x

As on CakePHP 3.x, `$this->view` working properly in controller.

After migration to the CakePHP 4.x version, it doesn't seems to work. Can't find any documentation under CakeBook 4.x.

Is there any syntax changes in CakePHP 4.x for `$this->view` or it's deprecated in newer version ??

Comment: For the future, make sure that your code is properly covered by tests, and that you upgrade to the latest release of your currently used major first, solve all deprecation warnings, and then upgrade to the new major.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with CakePHP 3.1, the Controller `$view` property is deprecated.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/appendices/3-1-migration-guide.html#controller

> view - replaced with template

In CakePHP 4.x use $this->viewBuilder() to setting and getting view options:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers.html#setting-view-options
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/search.html?check_keywords=yes&area=default&q=viewBuilder